# how to get record against same User_Id

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

I want to get all user records who have completed one course and appear in another course with `Isactive = 'N'`.

Like below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . window functions are one method.  This assumes that a course is on only one row in the table:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status = 'Completed' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user_id) as num_completed,
             sum(case when status <> 'Completed' and IsActive = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user_id) as num_noncompleted_inactive
      from 
     ) t
where num_completed > 0 and num_noncompleted_inactive > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from test where user_id in (
select user_id from test where isactive='N' and status in ('Completed','New') and 
(user_id,coursenumber) 
in (select user_id,max(coursenumber) from test where status='New' group by user_id) 
)
```